# Reflecting modified fields in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, updates, datarow

To get to my question, I need to do a little explanation first so bear with me.

This application has 2 forms. In the main form, I have a `DataGridView`. It is displaying data from a database table. Its `DataSource` is set to a `DataTable` object. Here is the code of the main form.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using DataAccess;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SqlDataAccess _dataAccess = new SqlDataAccess(); //SqlDataAccess is a class written to handle database related operations
        private DataTable _dataTable = null;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM fEmployee";
            _dataTable = _dataAccess.GetDataTable(query, null);
            dgvEmployees.DataSource = _dataTable;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Convert the current selected row in the DataGridView to a DataRow
            DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow dataRow = currentDataRowView.Row;

            Form2 f = new Form2(dataRow);
            f.ShowDialog();           
        }
    }
}
```

When clicked upon the row headers of the `DataGridView`, a sub form will appear. This sub form acts as a place to modify the selected rows' field values. A `DataRow` object containing the selected row's fields is sent to the sub form's overloaded constructor. And in that form's Load event, the data contained in that `DataRow` will be displayed in multiple Textboxes in the sub form.

The code of the sub form.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private DataRow _employeeDetails = null;
        private bool _isDirty = false;

        public Form2(DataRow empDetails)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _employeeDetails = empDetails;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtFName.Text = _employeeDetails["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = _employeeDetails["LastName"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = _employeeDetails["Address"].ToString();
            txtCity.Text = _employeeDetails["City"].ToString();
            txtPostalCode.Text = _employeeDetails["PostalCode"].ToString();
            txtCountry.Text = _employeeDetails["Country"].ToString();
            dtpDOB.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_employeeDetails["DOB"]);
            txtPhone.Text = _employeeDetails["Phone"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = _employeeDetails["Email"].ToString();
            dtpDOJ.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_employeeDetails["DOJ"]);
            txtBasicSalary.Text = _employeeDetails["BasicSalary"].ToString();
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In the sub form, the user is able to change the values through Textboxes.

Now to my question: How can I reflect the changes done to that particular row in the sub form, in the DataGridView in the main form?

Example - I click on one row header, it opens the sub form and loads the details. I change the First Name. And when I close the sub form, that modified value should be updated in the main `DataGridview`.

Can anyone give some suggestions on how to do this?

I tried passing the `DataRow` to the sub form as a reference but that didn't work.

Comment: Before closing the sub from,update the details in the table.call the bind method which binds the data from db for the Datagridview in Main form.

Comment: That option came into my mind too but I'm keeping it as the last resort. I'm trying to update the backend database from the main menu after doing all the modifications. :)

Comment: ok.Modified datarow is sent back to Main screen right?--create a function  and keep available all rows in datatable except the one you are modifiying.delete the row which you are modifying it.(you can do it based on primary key).After that import this altered datarow to the existing datatable and show it in grid.i hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Try to test this approach. You have to use the `DataRow[]` to update the data from `DataRow` selected. Please try to figure it out and get some idea.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    public DataRow[] mainDataRow;
    private DataTable employee = new DataTable();

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employee.Columns.Add("Id");
        employee.Columns.Add("LastName");
        employee.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        employee.Columns.Add("MiddleName");

        object[] emp1 = { "1", "Some1a", "Some1b", "Some1c" };
        object[] emp2 = { "2", "Some2a", "Some2b", "Some2c" };
        object[] emp3 = { "3", "Some3a", "Some3b", "Some3c" };
        object[] emp4 = { "4", "Some4a", "Some4b", "Some4c" };
        employee.Rows.Add(emp1);
        employee.Rows.Add(emp2);
        employee.Rows.Add(emp3);
        employee.Rows.Add(emp4);

        bs.DataSource = employee;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Convert the current selected row in the DataGridView to a DataRow
        DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        mainDataRow = employee.Select("Id='"+ currentDataRowView[0].ToString() + "'"); //get the primary key id
        using (var f = new Form2{ dataRow = mainDataRow, Owner = this })
        {
            f.ShowDialog();        
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataRow[] dataRow;
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var select = dataRow[0];
        lastNameTextBox.Text = select[1].ToString();
        firstNameTextBox.Text = select[2].ToString();
        middleNameTextBox.Text = select[3].ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm m = this.Owner as MainForm;
        var updated = dataRow[0];
        updated[1] = lastNameTextBox.Text;
        updated[2] = firstNameTextBox.Text;
        updated[3] = middleNameTextBox.Text;
        m.mainDataRow[0] = updated;
        Close();
    }
}
```